# SSSD hangs servers

Tags: sssd

When I boot the image from the diskless server (it is an RHEL 8.6) it gets Call Trace:
[image]

It looks like that sssd:2076 task is blocked on 120 seconds. I am not able to find anything about that in the network. Does anybody know how to resolve it?

Comment: `System Security Services Daemon (SSSD) is a system service to access remote directories and authentication mechanisms.` If your device is really configured to use remote services for authentication then one potential reason for the block is that those services can't be reached. Check network and the configured external authentication services for availability.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that cable led to many CRC errors. When it was replaced it start boot as always.

Comment: To clarify you mean network cable?

Comment: Yes, it was DAC cable.